# Use function to dynamically update another function's arguments object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use a simple plugin to add some functionality to my template:

```
$('.foo').ellipsis({
  lines: 3
});
```

What I want to indicate a number of lines to show with a function instead of a number:

```
$('.foo').ellipsis({
  lines: function() { return 3 }
});
```

This doesn't work for some reason. I am pretty sure this is not the plugins fault, but my misunderstanding of how it works. Any ideas?

A codepen is at:

http://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/qqNzZb

Comment: Which plugin are you using? This seems very plugin specific

Comment: https://github.com/jjenzz/jquery.ellipsis

Comment: Why would you do that? Can you post your actual use case?

Comment: @Cristy, I am specifying the number of lines with a data attribute, so I want to return something like `lines: function() { return $(this).data("truncate-lines") }`, however it doesn't work with a simple number too.

Comment: The plugin doesn't work that way... you could update the plugin source, or you could just do `$('.foo').each(function() { $(this).ellipsis({ lines: $(this).data("truncate-lines"); }) });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that code to work, the plugin would have to be built to accept a function as a value for the `lines` property. From the source, the only valid values for `lines` that I note are the string `"auto"` or a numeric value.

You would need to do something like this:

```
$('.foo').each(function() {
   $(this).ellipsis({ lines: $(this).data('truncate-lines') });
});
```

If you want to modify the plugin to support your code, adding the following as the first lines of code in `init()` would probably do the trick:

```
if(typeof base.opts.lines === 'function') {
   base.opts.lines = base.opts.lines.call(el);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, made it via the "each" method. That's new to me that not every function accepts another function as a value for it's arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The docs of jquery.elipsis do not indicate that the plugin supports functions passed into the `lines` parameter, neither does the source code.

One option would be to execute the function and passing in the returned value. However, this gives you little benefit over your initial approach, as the function is executed immediately:

```
$('.foo').ellipsis({
  lines: (function() { return 3 })()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to call ellipsis when the page loads.

```
// page load
// get data attribute
var ellipsis = $('elem').attr('truncate-lines')
// call the plugin
$('.foo').ellipsis({
    lines: par``seInt(ellipsis, 10)  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the object you pass, so that lines is a getter..

Also if you want finer control you can look at Object.defineProperty

```js
var obj = {};

obj.__defineGetter__('lines', function () { return 3; });

console.log('obj.lines = ' + obj.lines);

//$('.foo').ellipsis(obj);
```